# javafx fxml bring window to front form itself

Tags: javafx, fxml, scene

I need to bring to front `JavaFX FXML` window from itself. Something like this:

```
procedure (boolean close)
{
   if(close)
     current_window.toFront();
}
```

How should I get this window(scene) ?

Comment: If your current_window extends the stage, then just invoke `toFront();`

Comment: ((Stage)root.getScene().getWindow()).toFront() - giver error java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Text text = new Text("!");
    text.setFont(new Font(40));
    VBox box = new VBox();
    box.getChildren().add(text);
    final Scene scene = new Scene(box,300, 250);
    scene.setFill(null);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    stage.toFront();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: not from start(). This example shows how to operate another(child) scenes. I just need scene to operate itself.

Comment: why don't you use some `StackPane` it keep all scenes together one on top of other and could be used in something like above. Keep trying :)

I am not sure how much this will be helpful [link] https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to any of the nodes, you can use the following

```
((Stage)node.getScene().getWindow()).toFront();
```

Comment: Please explain what is node?

Comment: [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) is everything on the scene graph. It may be a control like a `Button` or a layout like `HBox`.

Comment: You may want to add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question to let us help you better.